# Infowindow opens only for last JSON record

Tags: json, google-maps, google-maps-markers, infowindow

I am trying to display `InfoWindow` but the problem is that I'm only able to see the last record of JSON.

`onmouseover` shows the title of other 2 markers but their `InfoWindow`s are not opening. Please suggest how to fix this code

```
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
for (var i = 0, length = json.length; i < length; i++) {
  var data = json[i],
  latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng); 

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: latLng,
  map: map,
  title: data.title
  });
}

(function(marker, data) {
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function(e) {
infoWindow.setContent(data.description);
infoWindow.open(map, marker);
 });

})(marker, data);
```

Comment: Never mind, I was very dumb to not see it first. I was adding click event after the loop. All I needed to do was to place closure inside for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I was very dumb to not see it first. I was adding click event after the loop. All I needed to do was this.

```
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

for (var i = 0, length = json.length; i < length; i++) {
var data = json[i],
latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng); 

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: latLng,
map: map,
title: data.title
});

(function(marker, data) {

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function(e) {
infoWindow.setContent(data.description);
infoWindow.open(map, marker);
});

})(marker, data);
}
```

i.e. closure had to be inside the loop